# Lost website rankings as a result of using a 302 redirect instead of a 301

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, https, magento, 302-redirect

I have an online store and during the last 2 days I noticed a big change in its SERPS for some keywords. The site is indexed in local Google for 5 keywords, and the online store is based on Magento 1.7.

5 days ago, I set up an SSL certificate in the online store in order to get better ranking results. I setup the SSL and followed the instructions from the Magento to make permanent `301` redirects from the HTTP URLs to the HTTPS URLs. I replaced all the URLs of the online store with HTTPS.

When I saw in the SERPS that the rankings for some keywords were going up and down, I checked some URLs to see if all was going well with `301` redirects and found that the redirects where `302` and not `301`, which is a big bug caused by Magento.

I solved the problem with the *.htaccess*, but still the rankings for the homepage have disappeared. I fetched the site again using Google Webmaster Tools and am waiting to see.

Can you please advise if I did something wrong, and what else I could do?

Comment: IMO I don't think your dip in ranking is simply as a result of using a 302 as opposed to a 301 status code.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a bit of time, your rankings of before should come back within days (or weeks at most). The drop is likely caused by the change from HTTP to HTTPS.

However, according to the Moz plugin, your page authority is 32 with 280 links, and your domain authority is 19 with 25K links. Your PA and DA are very low for such a number of links. You probably want to clean-up your link profile to improve your rankings.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am very bad because i am working hard for this site. I am really bad. Now for PA and DA, its because the site is sexshop. As Matt says, these sites have lower authority than the other because the backlinks have lower PA and DA. Please can you tell me how long time does it take to recover in serps as before? Also can you tell me that the lost rankings are because of 302 redirect or something else? Thank you

Comment: JVerstry user44093/georgeperis are the same person, most likely he/she forgot to login or changed browser.

Comment: Yes, I thought so... Just keeping the site tidy...

Comment: It's good you flagged it so we can take action, in this case it was converted to comment, nice one.

Answer (score 0):

Google might need confirmation after you applied 301 redirect right after 302 redirect. Give some time to these pages of your website. Once the redirects will be confirmed in the eyes of Google, you might start seeing your pages back. 
If you have waited for so long, do these two tasks.

1. Go to Google Webmaster Tools. Go to Fetch as Google and enter your desired pages there one by one.
2. Create some high quality relevant back links. This will help increasing the page popularity and will improve the rankings.
3. For the sake of better ranking, go to w3c validator. Try finding code errors and resolve them.

I hope this will help!